# Conditional Probability of Two Discrete Random Variables...

Tags: statistics

Two discrete random variables have the joint PMF given by the table:

[image]

found [here](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2e16u4h&s=9#.V0AXlD9Sw2E) . I need to find $\text{Pr}(X = x | Y = 0)$ and it seems to be to be just the first row of the table but the answers say $\frac{15}{20}, \frac{2}{20}$ and $\frac{3}{20}$ because the numerators are the same, I am thinking this is just a mistake. Am I correct?

Comment: Using `\mid` instead of `|` produces the appropriate spacing.

Comment: No this is not a mistake the conditional probabilities have to be renormalised to sum to 1.

Comment: How is that done? I'm glad it isn't just a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula 
$$
Pr({X=x| Y=0 }) = \frac{Pr({X=x \cap Y=0})}{Pr(Y=0)}
$$
$$\begin{align}
Pr(Y=0) = 20/50 \\
\end{align}
$$ 
$Pr({X=x \cap Y=0})$ is the first row in the table. This results in the probabilities 15/20, 2/20 and 3/20 respectively.

Comment: The numerator is the marginal probability that X = x, is that right?

Comment: actually Pr(X=x|Y=0) is the conditional probability, the numerator being joint probability and the denominator as marginal probability

Comment: marginal probability is the unconditioned probability ie P(Y=0) considering all possible values of r.v. X

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer!

Comment: Do you know how I would calculate the covariance in this case?

Comment: Covariance matrix is given by $$
        \begin{matrix}
        E((X-\bar X)^2)  & E((X-\bar X)(y-\bar Y)) \\
        E((Y-\bar Y)(X-\bar X))  & E((Y-\bar Y)^2) \\
        \end{matrix}
$$